# unable to get values from a login page in web.py

Tags: python, authentication, web.py

I am using python web.py framework to create a small web application which has just

1. Login screen (Authentication)
2. Screen with list of records(After succesfull login)

Presently i am trying to create a login screen authentication

I have created an `index.py` file with code as below

**index.py**

```
import os
import sys
import web
from web import form
from web.contrib.auth import DBAuth

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
  '/',   'Login',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='Python_Web', user='root', pw='redhat')

class Login:

    login_form = form.Form( 
        form.Textbox('username', form.notnull),
        form.Password('password', form.notnull),
        form.Button('Login'),
        )

    def GET(self):
        form = self.login_form()
        return render.login(form)

    def POST(self):
#        if not self.login_form.validates():
#            return render.login(self.login_form)
        post = self.login_form()
        username = post['username'].value
        print username,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>username"
        password = post['password'].value
        ident = db.select('user', where='user_login=$username', vars=locals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

My **login.html** code

```
$def with (form)

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Log in Details</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p><label for="username">Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="254" tabindex="1" />
    </label></p>
    <p><label for="password">Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="254" tabindex="2" />
    </label></p>
    <p><label for="Login"></label><button id="Login" name="Login">Login</button></p>  
  </form>

</div>
</body>
```

When i run the above file with url `www.localhost:9080` in browser i can see the screen with fields `username, password and login` button , but when i enter username and password and  clicked `login` button and tried to print the username i cannot fetch any data from the browser and the result showing is as below

```
None >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>username
0.0 (1): SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_login=NULL
```

Can anyone let me why i am unable fetch the details entered through browser ?, am i missing anything in the above code and finally all my intention is

to create a `login` page and `validate` the user details by checking in the database

and `redirect` to the next page if user exits

I request to please help me out in writing the code for fetching the details from the browser and checking in the database and redirecting to another html page if user exists. I am really stuck and breaking my heads to complete this process

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you validate the form before trying to access any of the inputs

```
def POST(self):
    post = self.login_form()
    post.validates()
    username = post['username'].value
    print username,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>username"
    password = post['password'].value
    ident = db.select('user', where='user_login=$username', vars=locals())
```

After that change the code works for me. Good luck!